# Python retrieve all items from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I combined two lists into a dictionary. Now I want to return all the names associated with a certain age. When I run below, I get an error shown in output below. How can I use my dictionary from my first function in my function 'people'

```
names = ['Katie', 'Bill', 'Cate', 'David', 'Erwin', 'Franz', 'Rich', 'Heath', 'Ivan', 'Justin', 'Kelly', 'Lauren']
ages = [17, 21, 17, 17, 19, 21, 20, 20, 19, 19, 22, 19]

def combine_lists_into_dict():
    dictionary = dict(zip(names,ages))
    return dictionary
print combine_lists_into_dict()

def people(ages):
    dictionary.get(ages, default = None)
    return names
print people('20')
```

Output:

```
{'Lauren': 19, 'Justin': 19, 'Kelly': 22, 'Cate': 17, 'Bill': 21, 'David': 17, 'Erwin': 19, 'Ivan': 19, 'Rich': 20, 'Franz': 21, 'Heath': 20, 'Katie': 17}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 50, in <module>
    print people('20')
  line 48, in people
    dictionary.get(ages, default = None)
NameError: global name 'dictionary' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems:

1. `dictionary` is a local variable, so the `people` function can't see it, hence `global name 'dictionary' is not defined`.
2. `.get()` looks up by key, not value, so it won't return what you want.
3. Passing the string `'20'` for an age, when ages are integers.

To solve #1, assign the dictionary returned from `combine_lists_into_dict` to a variable, and pass that variable to the function that needs it.

To solve #2, use a list comprehension to return names that match an age.

For #3, pass an integer.

```
names = ['Katie', 'Bill', 'Cate', 'David', 'Erwin', 'Franz', 'Rich', 'Heath', 'Ivan', 'Justin', 'Kelly', 'Lauren']
ages = [17, 21, 17, 17, 19, 21, 20, 20, 19, 19, 22, 19]

def combine_lists_into_dict():
    dictionary = dict(zip(names,ages))
    return dictionary

def people(D,age):
    return [key for key,value in D.items() if value == age]

D = combine_lists_into_dict()
print people(D,20)
```

Output:

```
['Rich', 'Heath']
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a dictionary to get the names you want. Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> names = ['Katie', 'Bill', 'Cate', 'David', 'Erwin', 'Franz',
             'Rich', 'Heath', 'Ivan', 'Justin', 'Kelly', 'Lauren']
>>> ages = [17, 21, 17, 17, 19, 21, 20, 20, 19, 19, 22, 19]
>>> [name for name, age in zip(names, ages) if age == 20]
['Rich', 'Heath']


>>> def people(target_age):
...     return [name for name, age in zip(names, ages) if age == target_age]
... 
>>> people(21)
['Bill', 'Franz']
>>> people(20)
['Rich', 'Heath']
```

---

If you want to use the dictionary (and the function that generate it), assign the return value of the function:

```
>>> def combine_lists_into_dict():
...     dictionary = dict(zip(names,ages))
...     return dictionary
... 
>>> dictionary = combine_lists_into_dict()
>>> [name for name, age in dictionary.items() if age == 20]
['Rich', 'Heath']
```

BTW, `20` and `'20'` are different. Pass `20` instead of `'20'`:

```
>>> 20 == '20'
False
```

Comment: Got it, but you can't pass one function into the next? Sorry this is the first time I've worked with dictionaries

Comment: @karmesto, You can pass the function (Functions are objects in Python). Or you can call it inside the function. `dictionary = combine_lists_into_dict()`

Comment: I see, perfect. Thanks for help/explaining